# How can I write native enum type for a column in rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

I have a table named users and I want to add one column with the name status and which will have these enum types ('pending', 'on-going').

So I tried something like this:

```
def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE TYPE statuses AS ENUM ('pending', 'on-going');
      ALTER TABLE users ADD status statuses;
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      DROP TYPE statuses;
    SQL
    remove_column :users, :status
  end
```

But this always leads to this somehow:

> Could not dump table "users" because of following StandardError
> Unknown type 'statuses' for column 'status'

What should I do here?

Comment: Have you tried `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` in `config/application.rb` to use `db/structure.sql` instead of `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: No. Its not added there. Let me try it now

Comment: @muistooshort But how do I add a column status with enum type in my schema.rb ?

Comment: You might not be able to without a lot of work but I always use `structure.sql` so I'm not certain. Doesn't matter though, `structure.sql` serves the same purpose while allowing you to use all the database-specific features you want.

Comment: While you can define column with a custom type in schema.rb the DSL does not support defining custom types. So it will just break as soon as you try to recreate the DB from the schema. As @muistooshort already said - you have outgrown the use case where schema.rb works which is fairly simple apps where you don't need any DB specific features.